# @Transactional does not work on getters of @Entitiy-annotated classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Why can't I make a @Transactional getter on a Hibernate based @ Entity class work?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - your idea smells like a bad design. Think about it again :) .

Secondly - @Transactional annotation will work on your @Entity class as long the latter is managed by Spring. And I'm guessing that your entity is not managed by Spring.

To make the entity transactional you will need to instantiate it using some kind of Prototype bean factory. After you read the entity from the session, you will need to associate it with Spring context again (consider Spring AOP or Hibernate interceptors for that purpose).

Comment: +1, but you should have stopped writing after the first sentence